# FireFireFire Kindle Fire stuck in strange bootloop

Tags: boot-loop, bootloader, amazon-kindle-fire

I have a Kindle Fire (1st gen) using the FireFireFire bootloader to boot TWRP and AOKP. It has worked fine for a while before. Now, I cannot turn it on when it is not plugged in. When it is plugged in, it automatically boots to FireFireFire, then turns off, then back to FireFireFire, and so on. I do not have time to choose a boot. I also cannot get ADB to recognize the device because it is never on long enough. What can I do?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did the battery run down all the way or anything of that nature? Anything else that may have changed recently, or did this start happening suddenly without warning? In some cases a fully depleted battery has caused people to see unusual boot behavior, and charging it via the wall charger (or, generically, any higher amperage charger) for a while will typically help.

Comment: The battery is full. It has taken a while to turn on before, but I have always been able to fix it in a few minutes. If it helps, I started to need to choose a boot option to go beyond the bootloader. Other than that, nothing strange has happened.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my kindle fire 1st gen.  i had to open the case, remove the battery connection to the motherboard for 20 seconds.. plugged in the battery and it started working again.